# I am tryna make an virtual assistant and facing some errors about GoogleAPI

Tags: python, google-api, python-3.9

**My computer is Windows 10 version:10.0.19041 python version:3.9**

*My code:*

```
    import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
    voice = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print(voice)
```

*Traceback*

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mt7da\Alexa.py", line 7, in <module>
    voice = r.recognize_google(audio)
  File "C:\Users\mt7da\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError
```*

*İf you need ```__init__.py``` it is here`[http://file:///C:/Users/mt7da/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Lib/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py][1]`**


  [1]:
````

Comment: does [this](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/383#issuecomment-462070857) solve your issue?

Comment: I looked at it sorry but it doesn't solve because in there it says mine is Ubuntu and code is different